In Node.js, fetching Label of file (Gdrive=> Sheet/Doc)but response gives id (Name is not there)
Used these:

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/list-labels?hl=en

const labelListResponse = await service.files.listLabels({
fileId: 'FILE_ID',
});

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/return-labels?hl=en
const file = await service.files.get({
fileId: 'FILE_ID',
includeLabels: 'LABEL_ID,LABEL_ID', // removed this line
fields:'labelInfo',
});

// 2nd one didn't work
Problem is that the 1st one is giving response in id, I want the Label name
[
{
"id": "nRfhyIFZkKP866Ie5sOk7jEykZogrTIE1wXRNNEbbFcb",
"revisionId": "10",
"kind": "drive#label",
"fields": {
"70F85091CB": {
"kind": "drive#labelField",
"id": "70F85091CB",
"valueType": "selection",
"selection": [
"30091A8CF3"
]
}
}
}
]
I want like : Confidential Google drive Sheet is labeled as Confidential

Please read formatting help
